# WCF Which messages to return after catching an exception?

Tags: wpf, wcf

I am using a wcf service and I know how to catch all the exceptions I need...
But I dont know which messages should I return?

My code:

```
try
{
    currentPosition = await locator.GetGeopositionAsync();
}
catch (FaultException<MessageError> ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(...?);
}
catch (EndpointNotFoundException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(...?);
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ...
}
```

I can return ex.Message but I dont want the client to know all the details, I want to show a short and helpful message.

What should I do?

Comment: The community of stack overflow does not know your users better than you do.  YOU need to come up with the particular error message that would give the best user experience to your clients based off of what you know about them.

Comment: It's true about FaultException<MessageError>... Here I know... But how to write the EndPoint message, it's something general

Comment: What do you mean "how to write the EndPoint message"?

Comment: MessageBox.Show("End point was not found....?"); or just to write MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky - Is your average user going to know what "Endpoint not found" means?  Why not return something like "Unable to reach service.  Please try again or contact help desk.", and then also log the exception message and stack trace to a log (file, database, etc)?  You could even generate a unique idea for the log entry and have the user contact support referencing that ID, so support could take a look at the logs.

Comment: Isn't it dangerous to give the stack trace (file, database...) to the client? For example: If I would crash facebook and they return me the table in the database there was an error, a hacker could make many things with this information...

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky - An even better approach (IMO) would be to implement `IErrorHandler` in your service and let the service catch the exception (and log it with detail information for review), and then return a user-friendly message via `FaultException<ErrorMessage>`.  This a) will prevent your communication channel from being faulted (due to an unhandled exception) and b) log the error at the source.  For example, if your service simply rethrows a caught exception with `throw ex`, you lose the stack trace.

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky - Yes, that is dangerous.  That's why I said **also log the the exception message and the stack trace to a log (file, database, etc)**.  You give the user a friendly error message and log the details for later review by the support staff/developers.  You don't give the exception message and stack trace to the user.  That information goes in the log for review by the appropriate people who have access to it.  All the user sees is a fairly generic error message, with possibly some direction to contact support with an id number for their reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have always handled this situation in a similar way to the way that @Tim suggested in his comment. I need as much information to be saved so that I can debug the problem at a later date, but as you said, we don't want to show the end user the developer `Exception` messages.

Therefore the solution that I use is simply to store the information that comes from the `Exception` in the database and to provide the user with 'user-friendly' error messages. Make sure that you also add code to record any `inner Exception`s as well if they exist. Now to address the question as to what to put in these messages... it really depends on your situation, but I generally follow this procedure.

First, I work out (either from forward thinking or from test results) which are the most likely errors to occur... off the top of my head, I'm talking about errors like 'no network access',  or 'invalid user security', etc.

When I have a number of possible errors, I will attempt to catch the exact errors with a number of `catch` statements as you have. Inside the handlers, I check for certain `Exception` messages and return pre-written user friendly messages for each. Finally, I add one last generic message to display for all unforeseen error situations.